# PHP - preg_replace to change emoticons codes for emoticons images

Tags: php

I would like to change all emoticons codes from my string to emoticons images.
Here is my array with codes and URLs:

```
$smilies = array(
    array('http://page.com/facebook-smiley-face-for-comments.png', ':)'),
    array('http://page.com/big-smile-emoticon-for-facebook.png', ':D'),
    array('http://page.com/facebook-frown-emoticon.png', ':('),
    ...
);
```

and here is script which change this codes for images:

```
foreach($smilies as $emoticon)
{
    $quoted_emoticon = preg_quote($emoticon[1],"#");
    $match = '#(?!<\w)(' . $quoted_emoticon .')(?!\w)#';
    $message = preg_replace($match,'<img src="'.$emoticon[0].'">',$message);
}
```

But I have one problem with that. I would like to change code for image only when emoticon code have space - before emoticon code and after emoticon code - example:

> Here is text **:--)** with emoticon.

I would like to change also code for image when emoticon is at the end of string. Then emoticon code should have added only space **before** code:

> Here is text with emoticon **:--)**

And the same situation with the begininnig of a string - emoticon code should have added only space **after** code:

> **:--)** here is text with emoticon.

Anyone can help me to create these regex ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex pattern to allow matches only if a certain emoticon code is not preceded or followed by non-space character:

```
...
$match = '#(?<!\S)(' . $quoted_emoticon .')(?!\S)#iu';
...
```